# Quorum - How to guard against DDOS if there are no gas transaction fee in private enterprise blockchain

Tags: quorum

In public blockchain, DDOS is thwarted via the use of gas transaction fee. In private blockchain (i.e., enterprise ethereum Quorum), how can DDOS be thwarted? Through throttling?

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong. security in private blockchains is from knowing your peers. Why would you need to anticipate attacks like DOS when it would adversely affect the attacker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though, in Quorum a user can send transactions for free, Quorum does not provide a DDoS protection more than what Ethereum do.

To verify the above statement, you can check Quorum documentation and you will find nothing about DDoS (Wiki: https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum/wiki). Additionally, you can go to Quorum and the original Ethereum repository and search for DDoS. It will give you the same results for both Code and Commits sections.

- Code: (the same 1 result)

  Quorum: https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum/search?q=ddos&type=Code

  Ethereum: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/search?q=ddos&type=Code
- Commits: (the same 2 results)

  Ethereum: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/search?q=ddos&type=Commits

  Quorum: https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum/search?q=ddos&type=Commits

Then why Quorum does not care a lot about DDoS, even though it charge free gas for transactions? Let us bring those points to attention:

- First, for any account to send any transaction, it has to contain some Ether. So, trying to send transactions from a fresh wallet will not succeed.
- Second, Quorum is supposed to run on a private network. This means that you can have more control on the network and people will tend not to launch an attack; because, most likely you will know the attacker machine and identity.
- The third thing is that you should consider putting your Quorum nodes behind a firewall that do a DDoS protection.

However, putting all previous in mind, you can still be exposed to some sort of DDoS attacks. And if it happens, you can do nothing but use the conventional ways to prevent and stop that. And in most cases this will be more than enough I think.
And I hope that Quorum will address this point better and work on some enhancements for this regards.

Comment: Thanks. Am worried that these quorum nodes may be hijacked

Comment: If there is a chance to hijack nodes or end-user machines, this could happen with Ethereum and Quorum. And this is the responsibility of the infrastructure (like Firewall & Antivirus). And the responsibility of the operators/users to not install Malware and Trojans.